# How to create a tape wrapped around an handle

Tags: modeling

Hi i'm very new to blender, and currently, just for beginning i'm doing some "homeworks". Now i'm modeling an hatchet and i want to add a tape around the wood handle.

Reference image:

[image]

Can someone tell me how i can do it or point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting with a [*Screw Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Screw) you could create the tape (spiral) from a plane:

[image]

Then add a [*Shrinkwrap Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Shrinkwrap)

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks stacker. And when the tape is overlapping by itself, there i should modify the mesh per vertex, there is no shortcuts fo that, right?

Comment: You should try to increase the screw factor to move them apart. The orientation of the plane is also important.

Comment: Never occurred to me to use a screw mod like this. Much easier than what I would have done and probably better results too.