# Twist rope around an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have this:

[image]

That's the hilt of a sword, and pretend that the plane is a small rope. What I want to do is achieve an effect similar to this:

[image]

But I can't find a good way to do it. As you can see I added a curve modifier and a nurbs curve, but getting the curve to follow the shape of the hilt is basically as difficult as doing it with the mesh.

I thought about using the shrinkwrap modifier, but I get this result:

[image]

I think shrinkwrap might be the thing I need, I just need to fix that problem.

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/how-to-create-a-tape-wrapped-around-an-handle

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This specific structure is a bit complicated by using normal methods, such as other guys suggested, However, you can do it quite well by a combination of a few modifiers:

1. Create the unit model for half round of the bandage;
2. Subdivide, tweak position of each vertex;
3. Model the other half round of that bandage.
4. Add Shrinkwarp, Array and Solidify modifier.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Tip:** **Shrinkwrap** modifier is always not so "accurate" by default, but using VGroup with weights assigned will make things more flexible.

[image]

**[example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3WTJzcHFjMjk0d2s/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic. For the first step, how did you twist the mesh? By hand or did you use some modifier?

Comment: You can see that it is fairly a simple mesh unit, so you can surely model it by hand quite fast. And it is even enough to model just half, since it is rotational symmetric.

Answer (score 9):

Using a bezier curve is a simple way to create the wraps.

I used [vertex snapping](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Snapping_Modes) to place the handles around the hilt of the sword. I then rotated the control points until the curve was close to the shape of the sword. The start and end of the curve should be in the same place.
[image: bezier curve]
Add a array modifier to the curve and give it a *Consent Offset* (I used `0.2`) to make the wraps down the handle.
Now move the overlapping handle the same amount as set in the array modifier, this will create a continual wrap.
[image: curve with array]

The last step is to give the curve some thickness. Do so by setting the *Fill* to *Full* and increasing the *Bevel* until the thickness looks good. Also increase the resolution to about `6`.

[image: curve settings]

This is the final result.
[image]

Comment: you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Nice try, I've tried this way, too. However, a big point here is: things will mess up when the bevel section is non-circular, like the OP's rope, because of the default tilt for each vertex on the path.

Answer (score 4):

I used this method [How to create a tape wrapped around an handle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/how-to-create-a-tape-wrapped-around-an-handle) and (after some tweaking) it worked really well! I want to add something, if you want the "rope" to have some thickness, use the Solidify modifier after you apply the shrinkwrap (otherwise all the faces will be wrapped around the object, you'll know what I mean if you try it). The end result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I try to do something like this I find it's easier to duplicate and separate a section of the mesh you are trying to wrap something around,
and use that as a base for the wrapping. I'm not sure if that would work in your situation, but I hope the idea's helpful

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) We like having comprehensive answers here. Is it possible you could add more information on *how* you might do what you suggest? (perhaps with screenshots?)

Comment: The base and the rope are already two separate meshes, if that's what you mean.

Comment: That's a nice idea! I didn't think about it.