# Screw modifier counterclockwise?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, screw-modifier

I am trying to create the green part of the pommel shown here:

[image]

I used the screw modifier like this:

[image]

I would like to duplicate the pommel wrapping and make it rotate counterclockwise to achieve a similar look as in the 1st picture .. but I can't figure out how. I don't know if this is actually the right way to do this.

Comment: In Object mode make copy of the existing pommel wrap and then use the same screw modifier on it but set Angle to a negative value.

Comment: Or you could apply the screw modifier then in edit mode select the wrap, SHFT + D to make a copy, then use  S X -1  to scale the copy in the negative X, (or use  S Y -1 ). With the copy still selected you will need to Recalculate or Flip the normals.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: I would simply make a copy and rotate it 180 on x or y...then apply the rotation...all the responses you were given before should work.

Comment: some alternatives also on this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/twist-rope-around-an-object/21433#21433

Comment: A simple and clean solution would be to add a mirror modifier after the screw modifier.

Comment: @Pyros You should post your mirror solution as the answer. It's by far the best one here.

Comment: It was an answer but a moderator decided to put it as a comment (and based on the title, it's true that it is'nt a good answer, just a good advice)

Answer (score 1):

Taking some information from the comments:

You have at least two ways to do this.

- **Option 1**: Duplicate the object, and set the Angle on the new object to a negative value.
- **Option 2**: Add a Mirror modifier after the Screw modifier (just one object here).

Note that with either of these, you may end up with [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) at the points where the two wraps intersect.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the *Screw* parameter in the modifier panel will reverse the direction of the thread if given a negative value.