# How would I go about making the cloth wrap around a weapon handle like this? Cloth sim or something else?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

[image]

Hi I was wondering how I could achieve this cloth effect for a game asset I'm making. Would it be smarter to model it or use cloth simulation or should I use curves?

Comment: I advise the beveled curves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Twist rope around object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/twist-rope-around-an-object)