I need help with making a katana base
I need help with making a katana base please.
I would like to sculpt the diamond shape into the katana base but I don't know how.


Is it possible?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/twist-rope-around-an-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19086/how-to-create-a-tape-wrapped-around-an-handle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121968/small-detail-problem

thank you. However that is hard to follow.

Which part? If you are having difficulties following one of the answers, you can edit your post and rephrase it to show us what you have gotten so far, and where exactly you are stuck so we can help. Editing it will automatically queue it for review to get it reopened.
